# CMake error when trying to add opencv libraries

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am trying to work with a depth sensor and trying to get the grayscale image and display it with OpenCV. I can access the data from the depth sensor without any issues. But I get the following errors when I try to include the OpenCV part in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
    CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (found suitable exact
  version "8.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:958 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake:67 (find_package)
  /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake:86 (find_host_package)
  share/royale-config.cmake:38 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks like the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "share")

find_package(royale REQUIRED)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

link_directories(${royale_LIB_DIR})

project (depthDataCallBack)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc)

add_executable(depthDataCallBack depthDataCallBack.cpp)

target_link_libraries(depthDataCallBack "${royale_LIBS}")

target_link_libraries(depthDataCallBack ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I am new to CMake. So any and all help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`project()` call should **precede** most of other commands call.

Normally, only `cmake_minimum_required()` and variables assignments may come before the `project()`.

Correct:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "share")

project (depthDataCallBack)

find_package(royale REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
link_directories(${royale_LIB_DIR})

...
```